# live ajax data based on data through php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

here is my index.html file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",

        beforeSend: function() 
        {

        },
        complete: function() 
        {

        },
        success: function(result) 
        {

        $("p").html(result.price);

        $("p").live("load", function() {
            $(this).html(result.price);
        });
        }
    });
});
```

and here is the ajax.php file (I didn't put json_decode and just put the val just like that for testing)

```
{"price":"o"}
```

what I'm trying to do is if I go to the ajax.php file and change the o to something else I want the data to automatically update and display on the index page without a refresh but I can't seem to get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you use firebug and check in the net panel how the request is

Comment: here you go i checked it but you can see also. i changed the php file to show a random number like rand(0,10000)   http://69.231.223.112:8888/test/

Comment: @same , you are getting resonse right ?? what is the problem then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client has no way of knowing that something on the server has changed. So you could use periodic AJAX requests with the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) function:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    // Every 5 seconds send an AJAX request and update the price
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $('p').html(result.price);
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

Another possibility is to use [push AJAX](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/07/pushvspull).

Comment: what is the problem in his code?? i didn't get what he is asking

Comment: @kobe, he wants to modify the JSON response sent by the `ajax.php` file on the sever and expect the client to update with the new value.

Comment: thanks, is live() the same as this or it has a different purpose?

Comment: @Sarmen, live binds an event to all matching selectors that exist when the DOM is loaded or at any point within the future.